# How to print natural number with comma as thousand separator in Java?

Tags: java

I create a method that will print natural number with comma and in somehow it's only work at the first thousand? here is my code:

```
private static void printWithCommas(NaturalNumber n, SimpleWriter out) {
    assert n != null : "Violation of: n1 is not null";
    assert out != null : "Violation of: out is not null";
    assert out.isOpen() : "Violation of: out.is_open";
    NaturalNumber th = new NaturalNumber1L(1000);

    if (n.compareTo(th) < 0) {
        out.print(n);
    }

    else {

        int ones = n.divideBy10();
        int tens = n.divideBy10();
        int hundreds = n.divideBy10();

        out.print(n + "," + hundreds + tens + ones);

    }

}
```

Comment: Given the non-standard `NaturalNumber` class, I'm assuming this is for a course you are taking. Have you tried recursively calling your method? Maybe `printWithCommas(n.divideBy1000(), out)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **DecimalFormat** class

## Example:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat)  
NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = formatter.getDecimalFormatSymbols();

symbols.setGroupingSeparator(',');
formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(symbols);
System.out.println(formatter.format(223423423));
```